# How to make a HTTP request with a custom verb when using Flurl?

Tags: c#, http, flurl

I need to send an `OPTIONS` request. How to I construct the client when using Flurl?

Comment: looks like the `OPTIONS` verb is not supported, but could be implemented as an extension. Currently supported are "Get", "Post", "Head", "Put", and "Patch" ([source](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/a025bf274b706bbb6bb080c721e0fd4143b9561a/src/Flurl.Http.CodeGen/ExtensionMethodModel.cs))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SendAsync` to specify a verb that isn't directly supported:

`"http://myapi.com".SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Options);`

If you need to send content (not likely relevant for OPTIONS), there's an optional `HttpContent` arg, and there are `SendJsonAsync`, `SendStringAsync`, and `SendUrlEncodedAsync` extensions to make that easier.